# Multiple hotkey - keyboard shortcut

Tags: autohotkey

In VS code the shortcut for "zen mode" is

CTRL + K Z

The explanation is this:
"Ctrl+K, let go of Ctrl and K, press Z

It's common in Linux to have such shortcuts, almost never seen in Windows."

My question is how to create this kind of hotkey in AHK?

Comment: Do you have a script written that just doesn't seem to work for you? If not, consult the beginner tutorial for autohotkey: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how to create this kind of hotkey in AHK?

One option is to use the `Input` command, which waits for a user to type a string:

```
; Press Ctrl+K then press Z within 3 seconds to display a message box.

^K::
    Input, key_press, L1 T3
    If (key_press = "z")
        {
        MsgBox, You pressed Z.  
        }
    Return
```

Where:

- `key_press` can be any variable name.
- `L1` indicates the maximum allowed length of the input (a single character i.e. "Length 1").
- `T3` indicates the number of seconds to wait before terminating the input (3 seconds i.e. "Time 3").

If you wish to make the comparison case sensitive, you can use `If (key_press == "z")` rather than just `If (key_press = "z")`. The first option (`==`) will only respond to e.g. a lowercase `z` whereas the second option (`=`, above) should respond to uppercase and lower case `z` (`Z` or `z`).

---

**References (AutoHotkey)**

- *[Input](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm)*
- *[If Expression](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm)*
- *[MsgBox](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MsgBox.htm)*
- *[Key List](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)*